# Trying to install package brms in R

Tags: r, stan

I'm trying to install the package `brms` in R so that I can rename the parameters returned from the function `stan` (from the `rstan` package). When I try `install.package("brms", dependencies=TRUE)`, I get the (partial) output pasted at the end of this post (it's too long to paste the whole thing). At the end of the output, you can see that I get a series of "dependency errors", which makes sense because the very first error is not a dependency error, but rather a compilation error that says:

```
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: init.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘statmod’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/statmod’
```

So the following errors occur because of this first one. But I don't know how to fix this compilation error.

```
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:439,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>’:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:300:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 1>’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:551:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 3>’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:98:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:178:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:46:50:   required from ‘class Eigen::QuaternionBase<Eigen::Quaternion<float> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:250:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::Quaternion<float>’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/Geometry_SSE.h:27:3:   required from here
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<float>::type’ {aka ‘__vector(4) float’} [-Wignored-attributes]
   55 |                      >::type PacketReturnType;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:370,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h: In instantiation of ‘struct Eigen::internal::find_best_packet<double, 4>’:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:22:57:   required from ‘struct Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:242:7:   required from ‘struct Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Quaternion<double> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/Geometry_SSE.h:88:47:   required from here
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:187:44: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type’ {aka ‘__vector(2) double’} [-Wignored-attributes]
  187 |          bool Stop = Size==Dynamic || (Size%unpacket_traits<PacketType>::size)==0 || is_same<PacketType,typename unpacket_traits<PacketType>::half>::value>
      |                                       ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:187:83: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type’ {aka ‘__vector(2) double’} [-Wignored-attributes]
  187 |          bool Stop = Size==Dynamic || (Size%unpacket_traits<PacketType>::size)==0 || is_same<PacketType,typename unpacket_traits<PacketType>::half>::value>
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:187:83: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type’ {aka ‘__vector(2) double’} [-Wignored-attributes]
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:187:83: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::unpacket_traits<__vector(2) double>::half’ {aka ‘__vector(2) double’} [-Wignored-attributes]
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:205:88: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type’ {aka ‘__vector(2) double’} [-Wignored-attributes]
  205 |   typedef typename find_best_packet_helper<Size,typename packet_traits<T>::type>::type type;
      |                                                                                        ^~~~
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:439,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>, 0>’:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:300:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>, 1>’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:551:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>, 3>’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:41:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:98:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:178:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 1>’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:46:50:   required from ‘class Eigen::QuaternionBase<Eigen::Quaternion<double> >’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:250:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::Quaternion<double>’
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Geometry/arch/Geometry_SSE.h:92:3:   required from here
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type’ {aka ‘__vector(2) double’} [-Wignored-attributes]
   55 |                      >::type PacketReturnType;
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:177: RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mice’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/mice’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mice’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘ape’ ...
** package ‘ape’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/BH/include" -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -include '/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp'  -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1  -I'/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c BIONJ.c -o BIONJ.o
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:88,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      | ^~~~~~~~~
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      |                 ^
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:96:10: fatal error: complex: No such file or directory
   96 | #include <complex>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: BIONJ.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ape’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/ape’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ape’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘statmod’ ...
** package ‘statmod’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c gaussq2.f -o gaussq2.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/BH/include" -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -include '/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp'  -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:88,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      | ^~~~~~~~~
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      |                 ^
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:96:10: fatal error: complex: No such file or directory
   96 | #include <complex>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: init.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘statmod’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/statmod’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘statmod’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘sp’, ‘terra’ are not available for package ‘raster’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/raster’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘mvtnorm’, ‘expm’ are not available for package ‘msm’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/msm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘msm’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘proxy’ is not available for package ‘e1071’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/e1071’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘e1071’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘bridgesampling’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/bridgesampling’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bridgesampling’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘emmeans’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/emmeans’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘emmeans’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘mvtnorm’, ‘RcppArmadillo’ are not available for package ‘projpred’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/projpred’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘projpred’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘tmvnsim’ is not available for package ‘mnormt’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/mnormt’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mnormt’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ape’ is not available for package ‘MCMCglmm’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/MCMCglmm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘MCMCglmm’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’ is not available for package ‘splines2’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/splines2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘splines2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘e1071’ is not available for package ‘classInt’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/classInt’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘classInt’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘sp’, ‘raster’ are not available for package ‘spData’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/spData’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘spData’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘evd’, ‘msm’, ‘gsl’ are not available for package ‘rtdists’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rtdists’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rtdists’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘bridgesampling’, ‘nleqslv’ are not available for package ‘brms’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/brms’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘brms’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘classInt’, ‘units’ are not available for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘sp’, ‘spData’, ‘sf’, ‘deldir’, ‘units’, ‘e1071’ are not available for package ‘spdep’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/spdep’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘spdep’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmptxMyN9/downloaded_packages’
```

EDIT:
If I just do install.package("brms"), I get a similar compilation error:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘mvtnorm’, ‘bridgesampling’, ‘nleqslv’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.1-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 166421 bytes (162 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 162 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/bridgesampling_1.1-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1679600 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/nleqslv_3.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 83731 bytes (81 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 81 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/brms_2.17.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5679524 bytes (5.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.4 MB

* installing *source* package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/BH/include" -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -include '/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp'  -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:88,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      | ^~~~~~~~~
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      |                 ^
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:96:10: fatal error: complex: No such file or directory
   96 | #include <complex>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: C_FORTRAN_interface.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvtnorm’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/mvtnorm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘nleqslv’ ...
** package ‘nleqslv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/BH/include" -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -include '/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp'  -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:88,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      | ^~~~~~~~~
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:628:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
  628 | namespace Eigen {
      |                 ^
In file included from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13,
                 from <command-line>:
/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:96:10: fatal error: complex: No such file or directory
   96 | #include <complex>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: init.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nleqslv’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/nleqslv’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nleqslv’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘bridgesampling’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/bridgesampling’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bridgesampling’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘bridgesampling’, ‘nleqslv’ are not available for package ‘brms’
* removing ‘/home/mdanb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/brms’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘brms’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmptxMyN9/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: What Linux distribution do you use?  Several have binaries that can help you.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Perfect, will write a short answer.

Comment: I ran into issues with missing `#include <complex>` when trying `update.packages()`, I solved them by starting a new R session and then updating.  See: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/conflict-with-rcpp/13507/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are (per your comment) on Ubuntu we can help you there.  There are two basic ways here which I will describe under 'Basics' and 'Deluxe'

##### Basics

See the section 'Get 5000+ CRAN Packages' in [this README at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) to install as all of the dependencies of `brms` and the package itself that way. In a R-on-Ubuntu-20.04 Docker container I just executed

```
apt install --no-install-recommends r-cran-brms
```

(and `root` was implicit, else add `sudo`) which adds 116 packages -- including `brms` itself.

Post if you have questions, either here or on the r-sig-debian list.

#### Deluxe

Also see several posts on [my blog below code/r4](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/code/r4/) about this -- and in particular
about `bspm`.  In the Rocker container `rocker/r-bspm:20.04` you can just say

```
 install.packages("brms")
```

in your R session *and it will install all packages as binaries* relieving you from any and all compilation woes. (I still prefer the shell and call `install.r` from `littler` but that is just my preference -- it still calls `install.packages`.)  How to setup the CRAN package [`bspm`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bspm) is described in its documentation, or you can just read the `Dockerfile`.

Again, if you questions please come to the r-sig-debian list.

Lastly, for the error you report, the suggestion by Robert goes in the right direction: you want break it down package by package and examine the error in the dependent package.  `brms` pulls is *a lot* making the binaries really attractive.

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
install.package("brms")
```

To avoid installing packages that you do not need according to your description of your goals. If it turns out that you *do* need additional packages install them one by one. If you need `terra` or `sf` and you do not know how to install these, then you can find instructions [here](https://github.com/rspatial/terra) or [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf) or elsewhere. And if all fails, you can come back here with a more focused question.

Comment: I get a similar compilation error when I do that (see the edit above)

Comment: Perhaps some other packages are out of date. I would first re-install `Rcpp` and then `RcppEigen` and try again.